# Google AdSense: Ads.txt not found error for nepalinformationhub.com even though accessible via URL

Tags: wordpress, web, adsense

I have recently integrated Google AdSense into my website, nepalinformationhub.com, and everything seemed to be working fine. However, I noticed that in the Google AdSense console, I'm receiving an error message stating "Ads.txt not found."

I've checked the URL for the ads.txt file (https://nepalinformationhub.com/ads.txt), and I can access it without any issues. I've also confirmed that the file exists in the root directory of my website. Despite this, Google AdSense continues to report the error.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before with the website nepalinformationhub.com or any other website? How can I resolve this problem and ensure that Google AdSense recognizes the ads.txt file on nepalinformationhub.com?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have checked the URL for the ads.txt file (https://nepalinformationhub.com/ads.txt) and confirmed that it exists. Additionally, I have ensured that the file is placed in the root directory of my website. I expected Google AdSense to recognize the ads.txt file since it is accessible through the URL. However, despite these efforts, Google AdSense continues to report the 'Ads.txt not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

I have had Adsense on my sites for years now and just today I noticed that one of them is reporting this error with the ads.txt file as well.

I can confirm the ads.txt file is there by visiting the URL, but Adsense is still telling me that it isn't there.

I can only imagine this is an internal issue with Google since the file is there and is accessible. So I'm not sure of how to fix it.

I'm curious if deleting the site and adding it again will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I checked your sites.
Everything is fine. Your ads.txt file is OK.
It's an error on Google. Do not worry.

Do not remove the site from the AdSense dashboard. It does not make sense.